# How to create a table of contents to Jekyll blog post?

Tags: markdown, jekyll

If I have a page/post in Jekyll with headers, is it possible to auto-generate a table-of-contents/outline for navigation? Something akin to the top matter of a Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That is the markup parser's task.

In case of Markdown one of the syntax extensions defines [Automatic generation of the table of contents](http://maruku.rubyforge.org/maruku.html#toc-generation):

```
* This will become a table of contents (this text will be scrapped).
{:toc}
```

This works in [Maruku](http://maruku.rubyforge.org/) and [kramdown](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: OK, it works but only if there is an H1 header in the markdown file, according to this: http://webiva.lighthouseapp.com/projects/38599/tickets/5-maruku-table-of-contents-not-generating-without-extra-h1-tag

Comment: Interesting limitation, @jjmerelo. I never hit it. Thanks for the information.

Comment: I also tried it in kramdown; but the problem was elsewhere: it bailed out with lots of messages if it found a mailto: URL in the text. Other that that, it should work.

Comment: Not working in kramdown 1.3.1, and could not find this option documented at http://kramdown.gettalong.org/

Comment: @CiroSantilli It's documented [here](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/converter/html.html#toc). _"Just assign the reference name “toc” to an ordered or unordered list by using an IAL and the list will be replaced with the actual table of contents."_ Note: it's not sufficient to just place `{:toc}` where you want the table of contents. `{:toc}` must be placed immediately after a list item.

Answer (score 12):

I have TOC for Jekyll blog which looks similar to Wikipedia TOC
[image]

So all my Jekyll posts have a Table of Contents section. It can be done just using kramdown.

Use this code inside your post where you want the TOC to appear

```
* Do not remove this line (it will not be displayed)
{:toc}
```

And use this CSS to style it like Wikipedia TOC

```
// Adding 'Contents' headline to the TOC
#markdown-toc::before {
    content: "Contents";
    font-weight: bold;
}


// Using numbers instead of bullets for listing
#markdown-toc ul {
    list-style: decimal;
}

#markdown-toc {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 1.5em;
    list-style: decimal;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Use appropriate colors that suit your blog.

That is it!

TOC can also be done with the help of [jekyll-table-of-contents](https://github.com/ghiculescu/jekyll-table-of-contents), if in any case the above method doesn't work. This one uses Jquery and a js file.

Here is the detailed guide on how I did it: [Jekyll TOC](http://blog.webjeda.com/jekyll-toc/)

Comment: I have try to do some syntax highlighting but can get it to work. I have pygments install with `pip`.

Comment: Is it possible to limit toc generation only from h2 to h4?

Comment: Kramdown can be controlled using these [options](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/options.html). Look for ``toc_levels``.

Comment: The easiest way I found to control levels of toc in kramdown is to simply turn off specific headers by putting {:.no_toc) in the line below the header you would like to switch off. This is where I found [these instructions](https://dieghernan.github.io/chulapa-101/cheatsheets/02-kramdown-cheat-sheet)

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/allejo/jekyll-toc provides very easy way to add TOC to your jekyll page.

1. Download the latest toc.html file (caution! should be raw file)
2. copy this file to _includes folder.
3. add this line before {{content}}: {% include toc.html html=content %}

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean a list of all H1, H2 elements etc in the content itself?  I don't think Jekyll has anything built-in to handle that.  I suspect the easiest way is to let Javascript generate it for you once the page has rendered, using something like [this jQuery plugin](http://www.binney.net/solid.things/jquery.autotoc/doc.htm), or one of the [many other plugins/snippets](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+table+of+contents+generator) available.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this [code](https://gist.github.com/cloudsben/6059930) before your contents.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yandex.st/highlightjs/6.2/styles/googlecode.min.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://yandex.st/highlightjs/6.2/highlight.min.js"></script>

<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("h2,h3,h4,h5,h6").each(function(i,item){
        var tag = $(item).get(0).localName;
        $(item).attr("id","wow"+i);
        $("#category").append('<a class="new'+tag+'" href="#wow'+i+'">'+$(this).text()+'</a></br>');
        $(".newh2").css("margin-left",0);
        $(".newh3").css("margin-left",20);
        $(".newh4").css("margin-left",40);
        $(".newh5").css("margin-left",60);
        $(".newh6").css("margin-left",80);
      });
 });
</script>
<div id="category"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All these methods specified didn't work for me for the GitHub pages blog, also I wanted to simply use the liquid for the purpose.

Here is the detailed description.

[How to add toc in Jekyll blog](https://ranvir.xyz/blog/creating-table-of-content-in-jekyll-blog-without-plugin/)

Here is how it looks.

[image: Jekyll toc]