# Can I access a page's table of contents in a Jekyll layout?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, kramdown

I have a layout in my Jekyll site for regular Markdown page, in which I'd like to place an outline of the page's headings. Can I access these headings in Jekyll or have them rendered in some other way, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the depths of the answers to a tangentially related StackOverflow question, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53807799):

> https://github.com/allejo/jekyll-toc provides very easy way to add TOC
>   to your jekyll page.
>
> 1. Download the latest toc.html file (caution! should be raw file)
> 2. copy this file to _includes folder.
> 3. add this line before {{content}}: {% include toc.html html=content %}

Answer (score 1):

There is also [jekyll-toc from toshimaru](https://github.com/toshimaru/jekyll-toc) on GitHub. You can configure which level you want to parse, h1 to h6.