# Multiple Converters/Generators in Jekyll?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I would like to write a Jekyll plugin that makes all posts available in PDF format by utilizing Kramdown's `LaTeX` export capabilities.  For each post in Markdown format, I'd like to end up with the normal `.html` post along with a `.tex` file containing the `LaTeX` markup and finally a `.pdf`.

Following the [documentation for creating plugins](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Plugins), I see two ways of approaching the problem, either with a Converter or with a Generator.

Converter plugins seem to run after the built-in Converters, so the `.markdown` files have all been converted to `.html` by the time they reach the Converter.

When I try to implement a Generator, I am able to use `fileutils` to write a file successfully, but by the end of Jekyll's cycle, that file has been removed.  It seems there's a `StaticFile` class which you can use to register new output files with Jekyll, but I cannot find any real guidance on how to use it.

Comment: Related for one big PDF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606606/jekyll-documentation-to-pdf-with-toc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the ThumbGenerator class in this: https://github.com/matthewowen/jekyll-slideshow/blob/master/_plugins/jekyll_slideshow.rb you'll seen a similar example. This particular plugin makes thumbnail sized versions of all images in the site. Hopefully it gives a useful guide to how you can interact with Jekyll's StaticFile class (though I'm not a Ruby pro, so forgive any poor style).

Unfortunately, there isn't really documentation for this - I gleaned it from reading through the source.

I wrote this a few months ago and don't particularly remember the details (which is why I gave an example rather than a workthrough), but if this doesn't get you on the right track let me know and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

I try to do the same but with direct html->pdf conversion.
It did not work inside a gitlab-ci pipeline at this time, nonetheless it work on my workstation ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137876/jekyll-generating-file-with-pdfkit-in-a-gitlab-ci-pipeline)) with a third possibility : a hook !

(here with pdfkit)

```
require 'pdfkit'

module Jekyll

  Jekyll::Hooks.register :site, :post_write do |post|

      post.posts.docs.each do |post|
          filename = post.site.dest + post.id + ".pdf"
          dirname = File.dirname(filename)
          Dir.mkdir(dirname) unless File.exists?(dirname)

          kit = PDFKit.new(post.content, :page_size => 'Letter')
          kit.stylesheets << './css/bootstrap.min.css'
          kit.to_file(filename)
      end
  end

end
```