# Create a PDF out of a complete Jekyll page with TOC

Tags: pdf, markdown, jekyll, file-conversion

I created a Jekyll page hosted on GitHub. This page is nothing but a step-by-step guide. I'd like to have all the content (i.e. all the markdown files/the content from within the pages folder) automatically generated as pdf with a TOC. Yes, there are already some questions on that on the board (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606606/jekyll-documentation-to-pdf-with-toc)) but none of them (nor my internet research) provides a tutorial-like guidance on how to really implement it end to end and generate the pdf. Can someone give guidance (preferably with a free to use library, so not e.g. Prince).

Comment: `wkhtmltopdf` might suit your needs...

Comment: @mb21: That's exactly the thing. Certainly, I stumbled over wkhtmltopdf but I'm missing a tutorial on how to implement it end to end and how to print out the complete content of the pages folder in my jekyll project. what gems do i need, what commands do I need to run. For experienced people, it might be  a piece of cake... anything available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply host your website on GitHub Pages or Netlify or even localhost, then use [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org) to convert a page to a PDF, like:

```
wkhtmltopdf https://username.github.io output.pdf
```

For detailed usage see [`man wkhtmltopdf`](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt).